# Name that graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

Let $V$ be an infinite countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Does there exist a graph (and if so, what is its name) such that for any $r=1,2,3,\dots$, the number of vertices in any annulus of radius $r$ and width one about the origin, i.e., $$ B_r(0)\setminus B_{r-1}(0)\,, $$ grows faster than any Gaussian in $r$? I.e., such that $$ \sum_{v\in V\cap(B_r(0)\setminus B_{r-1}(0))} 1 \geq \exp(a r^2)\qquad(a>0) $$

Comment: You can just put as many vertices as you like in each annulus if you want, nothing's stopping you!

Comment: @MishaLavrov, ok, but is there a name for graphs with this property?

Comment: It's not really a graph property. You can arrange the vertices of any graph with a countably infinite number of vertices to satisfy the inequality you want.